# oracle execution order and function calculations

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

Lets say we have a table which has 6million records.

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
  KEY1 NUMBER(15),
  ANALYSENO    NUMBER(15),
  ADDRESSNO    NUMBER(15),
  ABC          NUMBER(3),
  ABCDETAIL    CLOB
)
```

AND i have two queries.

first one:

```
 Select m.*,
        CASE WHEN dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$') = 0 THEN '' ELSE
        dbms_lob.SUBSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'##AAA')-dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$')-10,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC')+10) END) as SOMECALC 
 from MYTABLE m 
 where m.ABC = 1 
       and ROWNUM < 1000
       and CASE WHEN dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$') = 0 THEN '' ELSE
        dbms_lob.SUBSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'##AAA')-dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$')-10,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC')+10) END like '%AAA%';
```

second one:

```
Select a.* from
    (Select m.*,
        CASE WHEN dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$') = 0 THEN '' ELSE
        dbms_lob.SUBSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'##AAA')-dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$')-10,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC')+10) END as SOMECALC 
     from MYTABLE m 
     where m.ABC = 1 
           and ROWNUM < 1000) a 
     where a.SOMECALC like '%AAA%';
```

The only difference is that in second query calculation functions are not used on where statement. And be careful i m using ROWNUM < 1000 statement for where query.

So the questions are the following

1- is there any difference between two queries?

2- can we say that ROWNUM < 1000 statement calculated lastly in all statement execution?

3- using some functions (length, case when, instr etc) lazy evaluted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference between the two queries.

In the first query, you're saying fetch the first 999 rows which match all the other filter conditions.

In the second query, you're saying fetch the first 999 rows that have m.abc = 1, and then filter those rows where the somecalc field is like '%AAA%'.

You could well end up with fewer rows being displayed by the second query. If you moved the `and rownum < 1000` predicate to the outer query of the second query, then you'd have the equivalent query to your first query.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a syntax error in both the queries. You have an extra closing parenthesis in the CASE expression.

Anyway, coming to your original question:

> 1- is there any difference between two queries?

Yes.

> can we say that ROWNUM < 1000 statement calculated lastly in all statement execution?

No.

The difference is in the **filter predicate**. To understand it, compare the **explain plans**:

**Query 1**

```
SQL> set autot on explain
SQL> SELECT m.*,
  2    CASE
  3      WHEN dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$') = 0
  4      THEN ''
  5      ELSE dbms_lob.SUBSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'##AAA')-
  6      dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$')-10,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC')+10)
  7    END AS SOMECALC
  8  FROM MYTABLE m
  9  WHERE m.ABC = 1
 10  AND ROWNUM  < 1000
 11  AND
 12    CASE
 13      WHEN dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$') = 0
 14      THEN ''
 15      ELSE dbms_lob.SUBSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'##AAA')-
 16      dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$')-10,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC')+10)
 17    END LIKE '%AAA%';

no rows selected


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1231656364

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |         |     1 |  2054 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY     |         |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYTABLE |     1 |  2054 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<1000)
   2 - filter("M"."ABC"=1 AND CASE "DBMS_LOB"."INSTR"("M"."ABCDETAIL",'A
              BC$$') WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE "DBMS_LOB"."SUBSTR"("M"."ABCDETAIL","DBMS_LOB
              "."INSTR"("M"."ABCDETAIL",'##AAA')-"DBMS_LOB"."INSTR"("M"."ABCDETAIL",'A
              BC$$')-10,"DBMS_LOB"."INSTR"("M"."ABCDETAIL",'ABC')+10) END  LIKE
              '%AAA%')

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

**Query 2**

```
SQL> SELECT a.*
  2  FROM
  3    (SELECT m.*,
  4      CASE
  5        WHEN dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$') = 0
  6        THEN ''
  7        ELSE dbms_lob.SUBSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'##AAA')-
  8        dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC$$')-10,
  9        dbms_lob.INSTR(m.ABCDETAIL,'ABC')+10)
 10      END AS SOMECALC
 11    FROM MYTABLE m
 12    WHERE m.ABC = 1
 13    AND ROWNUM  < 1000
 14    ) a
 15  WHERE a.SOMECALC LIKE '%AAA%';

no rows selected


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 76631248

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |         |     1 |  4056 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW               |         |     1 |  4056 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY     |         |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYTABLE |     1 |  2054 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("A"."SOMECALC" LIKE '%AAA%' AND "A"."SOMECALC" IS NOT
              NULL)
   2 - filter(ROWNUM<1000)
   3 - filter("M"."ABC"=1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

You see the **COUNT STOPKEY** in the explain plan, that is due to the fact that **ROWNUM** is used to filter the rows. So in the first explain plan the `STOPKEY` is applied first, in the second query it is applied after `filter("A"."SOMECALC" LIKE '%AAA%' AND "A"."SOMECALC" IS NOT
              NULL).`